# Increase y spacing of grouped annotated horizontal barplot to prevent bar overlap

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I increase the spacing between the grouped barplot I have that has 3 bars per category without losing the correct annotations behind the bars? I have tried some things but all to no avail. Code I have for the barplots:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)

labels = ["Top1", "Top3", "Top5", "Top10", "Top20", "Top50", "Top100", "Top200", "Top400"]
baseline=[21,23,23,25,25,30,33,33,33]
native_shape_3000_apo=[14,17,17,19,20,20,21,22,28]
conformer_shape_3000_holo=[11,15,17,19,23,29,32,34,36]

x = np.arange(len(baseline))
print(x)
width = 0.4
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12,4), sharey= False, sharex=False)
axes= axes.flatten()
rects1=axes[0].barh(x - width, baseline, width, label='Baseline',color='black',edgecolor='black')
rects2=axes[0].barh(x + width, native_shape_3000_apo, width,label='x', color='yellow',edgecolor='black')
rects3=axes[0].barh(x, conformer_shape_3000_holo, width, label='y')

axes[0].set_xlim(xmin=0, xmax=47)
axes[0].set_xticks([x for x in range(0,48,10)])
axes[0].set_yticks(x)
axes[0].set_yticklabels(labels)
axes[0].legend(loc=4, prop={'size': 8})

def autolabel(rects, axes):

    for rect in rects:
        width = rect.get_width()
        perc=int(round(width/47*100))
        axes.annotate(f'{width} ({perc}%) ',
                      xy=(width, rect.get_y()+ rect.get_height()/2), 
                      xytext=(2,1),
                      textcoords="offset points",
                      ha='left', va='center_baseline',fontsize=6)
        
autolabel(rects1, axes[0])
autolabel(rects2, axes[0])
autolabel(rects3, axes[0])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current x-axis spacing value is 1, so if you expand it, the problem goes away. Now you need to adjust the width. The width of the graph below has been corrected to 0.5.

```
x = np.arange(0,len(baseline)*2, 2)
[ 0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16]
```

[image]